# Peer Review Plugin for Posts?

Tags: plugins, plugin-recommendation, publish

Is there a plugin that allows for peer review of articles before you post them?  IE, like a professional writer would send their work to a friend or editor to review and comment on their work before publishing it.

http://jmo.me/ideas/peer-review-wordpress-plugin
a pretty good explanation of what I'm trying to explain.

Answer (score 3):

The most comprehensive editorial system for wordpress I've found is "Edit Flow"

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/edit-flow/

Adds extensive post statuses, an independent editorial commenting and messaging system, and much more...

Comment: Edit flow is good if you have multiple people working on a blog. I'm thinking more along the lines of lone bloggers, trying to get some anonymous 3rd party feedback before they have embarrassed themselves on their blog. (assuming anyone is reading)

Answer (score 1):

Article you linked to describes more of a third party service rather than plugin.

WordPress allows to preview drafts. You can create accounts for friends/editors and send them preview link. Can probably be coded up a little for extra convenience, but as I see it could work just fine even with native functionality.

Comment: 3rd party would be great.  I could probably hack this out in a few weeks, but I already have a full time job and startup. 

http://editz.com/ comes closest I've seen so far.  But I want to do the reviews before I publish.

Answer (score 0):

[Author hReview](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/author-hreview/)

Add hReview and AggregateRating support based on schema.org, which help you increase search traffic by making SERP results more eye-catching. This plugin supports only the editorial ratings submission (edito/author rating), this means customers and site visitors are not involved in the rating or review process, this means rating reflects only the author's opinion.